# Fuse rows by name and sum values of all rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a file imported from tableau that I already transformed manually (to get rid of special characters i couldn't treat in the code and unwanted columns).

What I would like to do is to not have to treat it manually, but I cannot find the solution.

From the original Excel file I only need three columns I will name A, B and C. Once you remove all useless column, it will look like something like this (i don't write other column but we have to get rid of them).

**IMPORTANT : In the column C, it's not a whitespace but a special character :**
[image]

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| project name | reference 1 | $111 111 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $15 214 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $462 134 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $70 900 |
| project name 2 | reference 2 | $787 741 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $41 414 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $462 134 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $4 500 |
| *fused cell with above* | *fused cell with above* | $2 415 |
| project name 3 | reference 3 | $111 |
| project name 4 | reference 4 | $642 874 |

**Edit : A screenshot of fused cell :**

[image: A screenshot of fused cell]
On the final file, I need all lines to become one by doing the sum of value from C volumn, and put the result in the row where the project name is indicated.

Thank you in advance for your advices !

Here is my actual code to transform the file (yes I import a csv but the original file is an excel, the csv is after I transform the excel file manually :

```
elif typeOfFile == "9":
     #Import Excel file
     DataMonthly = pd.read_csv (filename, usecols = ['A', 'B', 'C'], sep=';')

     # Select only Wanted Data
     df=pd.DataFrame(DataMonthly)

     #Create a "DPAC" column and fill it with the specified code of the entity
     df['DPAC'] = 'code'
     firstCol = df.pop('DPAC')
     df.insert(0, 'DPAC', firstCol)

     #Create an 'Item' Column
     df['Item'] = np.nan
     firstCol = df.pop('Item')
     df.insert(1, 'Item', firstCol)

     df.columns.values[2] = 'A'
     df.columns.values[3] = 'B'

     #Create a 'Segment' Column
     df['Segment'] = ''
     firstCol = df.pop('Segment')
     df.insert(4, 'Segment', firstCol)

     #Create an 'EndCustomerCountry' Column
     df['EndCustomerCountry'] = ''
     firstCol = df.pop('EndCustomerCountry')
     df.insert(5, 'EndCustomerCountry', firstCol)

     df.columns.values[6] = 'C'

     #Create a 'SubSegment' Column
     df['SubSegment'] = ''
     firstCol = df.pop('SubSegment')
     df.insert(7, 'SubSegment', firstCol)

     #Create a 'TechnologyName' Column
     df['TechnologyName'] = ''
     firstCol = df.pop('TechnologyName')
     df.insert(8, 'TechnologyName', firstCol)

     #Define cols
     new_cols = ['DPAC', 'Item', 'A', 'B', 'Segment', 'EndCustomerCountry', 'C', 'SubSegment', 'TechnologyName']
     df=df.reindex(columns=new_cols)

     #Clean "C" column
     df['C'] = df['C'].str.replace(r'\s', '')
     df['C'] = df['C'].str[1:]
     print(df['C'])


     # aggregation_functions = {'C': 'sum'}
     # df = df.groupby(df['B']).aggregate(aggregation_functions)

     #Create Dataframe
     df = pd.DataFrame(data=df).reset_index(drop=True)

     if file_exists:
         df.to_csv ('C:/Program Files/Data_Arranger/Output Files/Monthly.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
     else:
          df.to_csv ('C:/Program Files/Data_Arranger/Output Files/Monthly.csv', mode='a', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: It's hard to give advice without knowledge about what _`fused cell with above`_ acutally is (i.e. how the original dataframe looks like).

Comment: I added a screenshot jere, it's litterally the fuse fonction from excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that your dataframe `df` that you get from reading the Excel/CSV-file looks something like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["project1", np.NaN, np.NaN, "project2", np.NaN],
    "B": ["reference1", np.NaN, np.NaN, "reference2", np.NaN],
    "C": ["$111 111", "$15 214", "$462 134", "$70 900", "$787 741"],
})
```

```
        A           B         C
0  project1  reference1  $111 111
1       NaN         NaN   $15 214
2       NaN         NaN  $462 134
3  project2  reference2   $70 900
4       NaN         NaN  $787 741
```

you could try

```py
res = (
    df.assign(C=df["C"].str.replace("[\$\s]", "", regex=True).astype("int"))
    .groupby([df["A"].ffill(), df["B"].ffill()]).agg({"C": "sum"})
    .reset_index()
)
```

to get

```
          A           B       C
0  project1  reference1  588459
1  project2  reference2  858641
```

The *writing back* is still a bit unclear to me.  If you want the totals to replace all individual contributions to that total, then you could directly do

```py
df["A"], df["B"] = df["A"].ffill(), df["B"].ffill()
df["C"] = (
    df.assign(C=df["C"].str.replace("[\$\s]", "", regex=True).astype("int"))
    .groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].transform("sum")
)
```

to get

```
          A           B       C
0  project1  reference1  588459
1  project1  reference1  588459
2  project1  reference1  588459
3  project2  reference2  858641
4  project2  reference2  858641
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comment, the second method seems to work, but how do I transfer the res data into my existing dataframe ?
Thank you :)

Comment: @Gatarlo I'm a bit unsure about how you want to merge the result back to the original dataframe: Does _"... and put the result in the row where the project name is indicated."_ mean that the original `C`-value gets overridden? Or do you want it in a new column?

Comment: Yes, I want it overwritten indeed, and the three column to replace the original, because I created other column I need to add even if they don't have any values :)

Comment: Do you know how I should do that ?

Comment: @Gatarlo In my last edit from Feb. 18 I had added one approach (I had removed the first solution that didn't seem to work and added the writing back part). Could you try it and see if it fits your needs?